# Is there a better way (fastest) to get the longest common folder path?

Tags: c#, list, performance, linq

I have a folder list,
want to get the longest common substring as output.

Here's my code, seems not very good,

How to improve these?

These files all from My `RecursiveSearch` function, It may be D:\123, E:\456, F:\a\e\eff, I save to xml.

Later read back from xml, want to get previous decision.

Files could be ten-thousands.
I do care about the speed.

```
var li = new List<string>()
{
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld1\eumaps\4.jfif",
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld2\eumaps - (2)\4.jfif",
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld4\ade\4.jfif",
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld4\abc\S.png",
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld1\file\Snipaste_2021-07-07_03-03-45.png",
};

//var shortest1 = li.OrderBy(name => name.Length).FirstOrDefault();
string shortest = li.Aggregate((a1, a2) => a1.Length < a2.Length ? a1 : a2);
string longest = li.Aggregate((a1, a2) => a1.Length > a2.Length ? a1 : a2);
string common = string.Concat(shortest.TakeWhile((c, i) => c == longest[i]));
// C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld       NOT MY WANT CAUSE THERE IS NO SUCH FOLDER.

if (!Directory.Exists(common))
{
    common = common.Replace(common.Split("\\").Last(), "");
}
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed that there is a common path? (I.e. are all files always on the C drive?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes. These files all from My RecursiveSearch function, It may be D:\123, E:\456, F:\a\e\eff,   I save to xml. I read back from xml, want to get my previous decision.

Comment: Why do you need a faster way? Did you measure that this is a performance bottle neck?

Comment: You write: `// C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld       NOT MY WANT.` So what is your expected result?

Comment: I am not sure that your algorithm correctly finds the longest common path. Try adding this entry in the list: `@"C:\Users\theodor\Desktop\fld4\abc\S.png"`

Comment: The OP likely wants to find `C:\Users\jared\Desktop`.

Comment: Do you want longest in terms of the number of characters or the number of subdirectories?

Comment: @AndrewMorton of course the longest common dir. Not C:\Users\jared\  but C:\Users\jared\Desktop

Comment: @JaredDC "Of course" is not helpful. _Of course_ it is clear to you, since you asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach would fail as you are just comparing the `shortest` and the `longest`, if there is any other path with different length and have different path in middle.

As per my understanding you want the output to be till the matched folder (not the substring of the folder or filename) i.e. `C:\Users\jared\Desktop\`

Here is my solution which runs in O(Nk) solution, Where N is number of paths and k is the shortest available length.

> Working Sample Code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6B8LIs).

This can also be done using the Trie Data structure in more optimized way (O(N + k)) but it would take extra space to build the Trie

```
    var folders = new List<string>()
    {
        @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld1\eumaps\4.jfif",
        @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld2\eumaps - (2)\4.jfif",
        @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld4\ade\4.jfif",
        @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld4\abc\S.png",
        @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld1\file\Snipaste_2021-07-07_03-03-45.png",
    };
    
    var minPathLength = folders.Min(x => x.Length);
    
    var maxCommonPath = new StringBuilder();
    var currentCommonPath = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < minPathLength; i++)
    {
        var boolAllSame = true;
        var c = folders[0][i];
        boolAllSame = folders.All(x => x[i] == c);
        
        if (boolAllSame)
        {
            currentCommonPath.Append(c);
            if (c == '\\')
            {
                maxCommonPath.Append(currentCommonPath.ToString());
                currentCommonPath = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    
    var result = maxCommonPath.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: If it still take more time with the input paths that you have, try once using Trie data structure which will run more faster.

Comment: You could consider comparing the characters with case-insensitivity (`Char.ToUpperInvariant`), to allow for matching equal paths with case differences.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, You are correct, But as we are not sure of the inputs, lets Jared decide what he wants. Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a succinct, but not particularly performant implementation that uses Linq. It also has a dependency on the [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) package, for the [`Transpose`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Transpose.cs) operator:

```
var paths = new List<string>()
{
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld1\eumaps\4.jfif",
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld2\eumaps - (2)\4.jfif",
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld4\ade\4.jfif",
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld4\abc\S.png",
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld1\file\Snipaste_2021-07-07_03-03-45.png",
};
string[] longestCommonPathComponents = paths
    .Select(path => path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))
    .Transpose()
    .Select(parts => parts.Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .TakeWhile(distinct => distinct.Count() == 1)
    .Select(distinct => distinct.First())
    .ToArray();
string longestCommonPath = Path.Combine(longestCommonPathComponents);
Console.WriteLine($"Longest common path: {longestCommonPath}");
```

Output:

> Longest common path: C:/Users/jared/Desktop

[Try it on fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FyBPoj).

The signature of the `Transpose` operator:

```
// Transposes a sequence of rows into a sequence of columns.
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Transpose<T>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var li = new List<string>()
{
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld1\eumaps\4.jfif",
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld2\eumaps - (2)\4.jfif",
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld4\ade\4.jfif",
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld4\abc\S.png",
    @"C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld1\file\Snipaste_2021-07-07_03-03-45.png",
};

string first = li.First();
int n = 0;

while (li.All(x => x.Length > n && x[n] == first[n]))
    n++;

string longestCommon = first.Substring(0, n); // C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld
```

You say `C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld` is not what you want, but what do you want? The most nested valid folder? Just pull to the last slash, or use Path methods to get the bit you want.

Comment: There is no such folder:  C:\Users\jared\Desktop\fld

Comment: So do as I suggested and just pull to the last slash? eg `var folder = longestCommon.Substring(0, longestCommon.LastIndexOf('\'));`

Answer (score -3):

suggestion:
use this code for your image paths

```
var li = new List<string>()
{
Application.StartupPath + "/Images/1.png",
Application.StartupPath + "/Images/2.png",
Application.StartupPath + "/Images/3.png",
}
```

Comment: Did you actually read the question? This doesn't have any relevance at all.

Comment: Application save the xml in the application folder, the xml file record the files in the Desktop folder.